# Is this sentence correct?

Tags: traducción, gramática, verbos, expresiones, significado

*****estar en viaje***

Does this sentence exist? Someone said it means 'i'm on a business trip'

Comment: It means to be "on a trip". Not necessarily a *business trip* It's best to say **de viaje** but *en* is ok. it is like in English saying "on a trip" or saying "traveling".

Answer (score 3):

This is the fact "**to be on travel**" = "**estar en viaje**" (literally).

Makes sense if you try to say e.g. "*At 12:00 I will be on travel*" (which sounds quite strange even in english).

In english, instead of "...**on travel**", we use to say "...**on the way**."
In spanish it's fine to say "A las 12:00 voy a **estar en viaje**," but the way we say it is "...**en camino**."

---

#### Edit / Summary

- "I'm on the way" translates to "Estoy en camino."
- "I'm on a trip" translates to "Estoy de viaje."
- "Estar en viaje" is no wrong, but no one says that.

Comment: No sería estar *de* viaje?

Comment: @tac seguramente sí. En su momento lo interpreté como "estar en camino" (algo más puntual), ahora lo veo más como "estar de viaje." De hecho la pregunta se cerró, probablemente por falta de contexto.